# Why does the interpretation of division operation change among SPARQL processors of Jean and Sesame/OpenRDF?

Tags: sparql, jena, sesame

The following SPARQL query produces different results when run on the SPARQL engines of two popular SDKs ([Jena](http://jena.apache.org/) and [Sesame / OpenRDF](http://www.openrdf.org/)):

```
PREFIX xsd:<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT  ?v1 ?v2 ?v3 ?v4 ?v5 ?v6
WHERE
{
    BIND (            1    / 3             as ?v1)
    BIND (  xsd:float(1    / 3)            as ?v2)
    BIND (  xsd:float(1)   / 3             as ?v3)
    BIND ( (          1.0  / 3)            as ?v4)
    BIND (  xsd:float(1.0  / 3)            as ?v5)
    BIND (  xsd:float(1.0) / 3             as ?v6)
}
```

the results of the latest version of Jena make sense to me (formatted for readability):

```
v1: 0.333333333333333333333333
v2: "0.333333333333333333333333"^^xsd:float
v3: "0.33333334"^^xsd:float
v4: 0.333333333333333333333333
v5: "0.333333333333333333333333"^^xsd:float
v6: "0.33333334"^^xsd:float
```

on the other hand the latest version of Sesame/OpenRDF returns (formatted for readability):

```
v1: "0"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal>
v2: "0.0"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>
v3: "0.33333334"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>
v4: "0.3"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal>
v5: "0.3"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>
v6: "0.33333334"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float>
```

To stress the point: Jena never returns 0 or 0.0 or 0.3 like Sesame/OpenRDF does. Can anybody give an explanation why there is such a difference in numeric results? And how to get the same result to the same SPARQL query? Or, which one is correct (in the sense that implementing the SPARQL standard correctly regardless of mathematical correctness)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is explained by a different rounding/scaling strategy employed in Sesame's implementation of the division operator.

The first operator:

```
1 / 3 as ?v
```

divides two integer values and binds the result to ?v, which will be a value of type decimal.

Since 1/3 is a fraction with non-terminating decimal expansion, we need to round the result. However, since the scale (i.e. the number of decimals) of the two input variables is zero, Sesame's MathUtil sets the scale of the result to zero as well, so the result of the division (0.3333...) is scaled to zero digits and rounded, which results in 0.

You can get around this in Sesame by explicitly adding scale to your input values. For example:

```
SELECT  ?v1 
WHERE
{
    BIND ( 1.0000 / 3 as ?v1)
}
```

will result in:

```
?v1:  "0.3333"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#decimal>
```

Note that what we actually do here is change one of your input values from an integer to a decimal. It's somewhat similar to how doing 1/3 in Java will result in 0, but you can get around that by casting to double.

As far as I can tell from the XPath specs (which defines the division operator that SPARQL reuses), both Jena and Sesame behave conform the spec, as the choice of a scaling number on numeric operations is implementation-defined.

Of course, that's not to say that it wouldn't be more practical if Sesame actually used a higher precision on such repeating fractions when doing division. Logged as an improvement request at http://www.openrdf.org/issues/browse/SES-1063, and since it is a trivial thing to do, this will be supported in the next release. In the meantime, I hope the above gives you a suitable workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the improvement request. A question: should the number of digits impact the precision of arithmetic? I think it should not which seems to be the case for OpenRDF/Sesame.

Comment: Well, it depends on how you look at it. Any precision we use is arbitrary, in a sense, because it always remains an approximation of the actual value. Relying on the precision of the input is normal when doing statistics: how can any outcome be more precise than the data you provide as input? But as I said: using a large fixed precision for repeating fractions is of course more practical than purely relying on the precision of the input.